# Bootstrap 4 Column height in mobile vs desktop

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have two columns for desktop of size `6` each.

[image]

In mobile, I need these columns to fit  the height of the phone, i.e.

[image]

How can we have variable height with Bootstrap 4 according to devices?

What I have used is,

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-xl-6 h-100"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 h-100"></div>
</div>
```

How to have that `h-100` vary according to device, like `h-sm-50` and `h-xl-100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no height class vary according to device

the only available thing is vary according to viewport [bootstrap Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/)

so you can use custom class to assign full height only on mobile view using [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Example

HTML

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-xl-6 mobile-100"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 mobile-100"></div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-100 {height:100vh}
}
```

Comment: `.mobile-50 {height:50vh}` with media query worked. Thanks @Ahmed

Comment: You're welcome , i thought that you need it to be full height on mobile .

Comment: As in the question, height of each column is 50% on phone. @Ahmed